# trying format json a certain way in PHP using array from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to build a restful web service for my website.  I have a php mysql query using the following code:

```
function mysql_fetch_rowsarr($result, $taskId, $num, $count){
  $got = array();
  if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
    return $got;
  mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $got[]=$row;
}
  print_r($row)
  print_r(json_encode($result));
  return $got;
```

which returns the following using the print_r($data) in the code above

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [show] => Blip TV Photoshop Users TV [region] => UK [url] => http://blip.tv/photoshop-user-tv/rss [resourceType] => RSS / Atom feed [plugin] => Blip TV ) [1] => Array ( [show] => TV Highlights [region] => UK [url] => http://feeds.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/highlights/tv [resourceType] => RSS / Atom feed [plugin] => iPlayer (UK) ) )
```

Here is the json it returns:

```
 [{"show":"Blip TV Photoshop Users TV","region":"UK","url":"http:\/\/blip.tv\/photoshop-user-tv\/rss","resourceType":"RSS \/ Atom feed","plugin":"Blip TV"},{"show":"TV Highlights","region":"UK","url":"http:\/\/feeds.bbc.co.uk\/iplayer\/highlights\/tv","resourceType":"RSS \/ Atom feed","plugin":"iPlayer (UK)"}]
```

I am using the following code to add some items to the array then convert it to json and return the json.

```
 $got=array(array("resource"=>$taskId,"requestedSize"=>$num,"totalSize"=>$count,"items"),$got);
```

using the following code to convert it to json and return it.

```
 $response->body = json_encode($result);
 return $response;
```

this gives me the following json.

```
[{"resource":"video","requestedSize":2,"totalSize":61,"0":"items"},[{"show":"Blip TV Photoshop Users TV","region":"UK","url":"http:\/\/blip.tv\/photoshop-user-tv\/rss","resourceType":"RSS \/ Atom feed","plugin":"Blip TV"},{"show":"TV Highlights","region":"UK","url":"http:\/\/feeds.bbc.co.uk\/iplayer\/highlights\/tv","resourceType":"RSS \/ Atom feed","plugin":"iPlayer (UK)"}]]
```

The consumers of the API want the json in the following format and I cannot figure out how to get it to come out this way.  I have searched and tried everything I can find and still not get it.  And I have not even started trying to get the xml formatting

```
 {"resource":"video", "returnedSize":2, "totalSize":60,"items":[{"show":"Blip TV Photoshop Users TV","region":"UK","url":"http://blip.tv/photoshop-user-tv/rss","resourceType":"RSS / Atom feed","plugin":"Blip TV"},{"show":"TV Highlights","region":"UK", "url":"http://feeds.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/highlights/tv","resourceType":"RSS / Atom feed","plugin":"iPlayer (UK)"}]}
```

I appreciate any and all help with this.  I have setup a copy of the database with readonly access and can give all the source code it that will help, I will warn you that I am just now learning php, I learned to program in basic, fortran 77 so the php is pretty messy and I would guess pretty bloated.

OK The above about json encoding was answered.  The API consumers also want the special character "/", not to be escaped since it is a URL.  I tried the "JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES " in the json_encode and got the following error.

```
 json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long
```

Comment: Apply `json_decode` to the desired json output and see what array you need to assemble to get the same

Comment: how can I get the desired json into php?  can I make it a string then json)decode the string?

Comment: "The consumers of the API want the json in the following format " --- this is the desired format, the following one. The one your consumers want is obviously a desired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$result` line should look like

```
$result=array(
    "resource"=>$taskId,
    "requestedSize"=>$num,
    "totalSize"=>$count,
    "items" => $got
);
```

Comment: funny how easy it is once someone puts the correct answer under your nose.

Comment: You would get the same if you used `json_decode` with the line you want to achieve (the last json in your question)

Comment: I made a small change to the question, I tried to add the JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES to the json_encode and get the following.   Warning: json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in

Comment: @Moltra: as it said in documentation (http://nz.php.net/json_encode) that constant was introduced in php 5.4. Obviously you use some older version

Comment: Yes I am using PHP Version: PHP 5.3 Is there anyway around this using php 5.3 that is the current php on godaddy 4GH.

Comment: @Moltra: not sure. Why do you need that option?

Comment: That is what the API consumers asked for.

Comment: @Moltra: escaped slashes is a still **valid** JSON. Your consumers are too capricious